# What did the early church fathers (pre-5th c.) teach with regards to baptismal regeneration?

Tags: baptism, church-fathers

The title says it all, really.

What did the ECF believe and teach with regards to baptismal regeneration?

Did they generally subscribe to it or deny it?

Related: [What did the early church fathers (pre-5th c.) teach with regards to the doctrine of baptism as a necessity for salvation?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/45359/what-did-the-early-church-fathers-pre-5th-c-teach-with-regards-to-the-non-s)

Comment: Cf. [The Church Fathers on Baptismal Regeneration](http://www.calledtocommunion.com/2010/06/the-church-fathers-on-baptismal-regeneration/)

Answer (score 2):

Justin Martyr wrote a chapter (LXI) on Christian baptism in his *First Apology*, written sometime in the 2nd century:

> I will also relate the manner in which we dedicated ourselves to God
>   when we had been made new through Christ; lest, if we omit this, we
>   seem to be unfair in the explanation we are making. As many as are
>   persuaded and believe that what we teach and say is true, and
>   undertake to be able to live accordingly, are instructed to pray and
>   to entreat God with fasting, for the remission of their sins that are
>   past, we praying and fasting with them. Then they are brought by us
>   where there is water, and are regenerated in the same manner in which
>   we were ourselves regenerated. For, in the name of God, the Father and
>   Lord of the universe, and of our Saviour Jesus Christ, and of the Holy
>   Spirit, they then receive the washing with water. For Christ also
>   said, *Except ye be born again, ye shall not enter into the kingdom of
>   heaven* [John 3:5].  Now, that it is impossible for those who have
>   once been born to enter into their mothers’ wombs, is manifest to all.
>   And how those who have sinned and repent shall escape their sins, is
>   declared by Isaiah the prophet, as I wrote above, he thus speaks:
>   *Wash you, make you clean; put away the evil of your doings from your souls; learn to do well; judge the fatherless, and plead for the
>   widow: and come and let us reason together, saith the Lord. And though
>   your sins be as scarlet, I will make them white like wool; and though
>   they be as crimson, I will make them white as snow. But if ye refuse
>   and rebel, the sword shall devour you: for the mouth of the Lord hath
>   spoken it* [Isaiah 1:16-20]. 
>  And for this [rite] we have
>   learned from the apostles this reason. Since at our birth we were born
>   without our own knowledge or choice, by our parents coming together,
>   and were brought up in bad habits and wicked training; in order that
>   we may not remain the children of necessity and of ignorance, but may
>   become the children of choice and knowledge, and may obtain in the
>   water the remission of sins formerly committed, there is pronounced
>   over him who chooses to be born again, and has repented of his sins,
>   the name of God the Father and Lord of the universe; he who leads to
>   the laver the person that is to be washed calling him by this name
>   alone. For no one can utter the name of the ineffable God; and if any
>   one dare to say that there is a name, he raves with a hopeless
>   madness. And this washing is called illumination, because they who
>   learn these things are illuminated in their understandings. And in the
>   name of Jesus Christ, who was crucified under Pontius Pilate, and in
>   the name of the Holy Ghost, who through the prophets foretold all
>   things about Jesus, he who is illuminated is washed.

Cyprian of Carthage, another Ante-Nicene Father, wrote in the 3rd century of his own baptism:

> For as I myself was held in bonds by the innumerable errors of my
>   previous life, from which I did not believe that I could by
>   possibility be delivered, so I was disposed to acquiesce in my
>   clinging vices; and because I despaired of better things, I used to
>   indulge my sins as if they were actually parts of me, and indigenous
>   to me. But after that, by the help of the water of new birth [i.e.,
>   baptism], the stain of former years had been washed away, and a light
>   from above, serene and pure, had been infused into my reconciled
>   heart,—after that, by the agency of the Spirit breathed from heaven, a
>   second birth had restored me to a new man;—then, in a wondrous manner,
>   doubtful things at once began to assure themselves to me, hidden
>   things to be revealed, dark things to be enlightened, what before had
>   seemed difficult began to suggest a means of accomplishment, what had
>   been thought impossible, to be capable of being achieved; so that I
>   was enabled to acknowledge that what previously, being born of the
>   flesh, had been living in the practice of sins, was of the earth
>   earthly, but had now begun to be of God, and was animated by the
>   Spirit of holiness (*Epistle I, To Donatus*).

These are the earliest sources I could find who comment on the nature of baptism.  I am sure there are many, many such commentaries among the Post-Nicene Fathers, but rather than search through them I thought I would simply quote what John of Damascus wrote later in his *An Exact Exposition of the Orthodox Faith*.  Written in the early 8th century, *Exposition* was probably the first summary of Church dogmatic theology and reflects the collected teaching of recognized Church Fathers up to that point.  In "Concerning Faith and Baptism", he writes:

> We confess one baptism for the remission of sins and for life eternal.
>   For baptism declares the Lord’s death. We are indeed *buried with the
>   Lord through baptism* [Col 2:12], as saith the divine Apostle. So
>   then, as our Lord died once for all, we also must be baptized once for
>   all, and baptized according to the Word of the Lord, *In the Name of
>   the Father, and of the Son, and of the Holy Spirit* [Matt 28:19],
>   being taught the confession in Father, Son, and Holy Spirit.  
>   The baptism then into Christ means that believers are baptized into
>   Him. We could not believe in Christ if we were not taught confession
>   in Father, Son, and Holy Spirit4. For Christ is the Son of the Living
>   God5, Whom the Father anointed with the Holy Spirit: in the words of
>   the divine David, *Therefore God, thy God, hath anointed thee with the
>   oil of gladness above thy fellows* [Ps 44:7 LXX]. And Isaiah also
>   speaking in the person of the Lord says, T*he Spirit of the Lord is
>   upon me because He hath anointed me* [61:1]. Christ, however, taught
>   His own disciples the invocation and said, *Baptizing them in the Name
>   of the Father, and of the Son, and of the Holy Spirit*. For since
>   Christ made us for incorruption, and we transgressed His saving
>   command. He condemned us to the corruption of death in order that that
>   which is evil should not be immortal, and when in His compassion He
>   stooped to His servants and became like us, He redeemed us from
>   corruption through His own passion. He caused the fountain of
>   remission to well forth for us out of His holy and immaculate side [Jn
>   19:34], water for our regeneration, and the washing away of sin and
>   corruption; and blood to drink as the hostage of life eternal. And He
>   laid on us the command to be born again of water and of the Spirit [Jn
>   3:5], through prayer and invocation, the Holy Spirit drawing nigh unto
>   the water. For since man’s nature is twofold, consisting of soul and
>   body, He bestowed on us a twofold purification, of water and of the
>   Spirit: the Spirit renewing that part in us which is after His image
>   and likeness, and the water by the grace of the Spirit cleansing the
>   body from sin and delivering it from corruption, the water indeed
>   expressing the image of death, but the Spirit affording the earnest of
>   life. 
>  For from the beginning *the Spirit of God moved upon
>   the face of the waters* [Gn 1:2], and anew the Scripture witnesseth
>   that water has the power of purification [Lev 15:10]. In the time of
>   Noah God washed away the sin of the world by water [Gn 16:17]. By
>   water every impure person is purified, according to the law, even the
>   very garments being washed with water. Elijah shewed forth the grace
>   of the Spirit mingled with the water when he burned the holocaust by
>   pouring on water [3 Kingdoms 18:32 LXX]. And almost everything is
>   purified by water according to the law: for the things of sight are
>   symbols of the things of thought. The regeneration, however, takes
>   place in the spirit: for faith has the power of making us sons (of
>   God), creatures as we are, by the Spirit, and of leading us into our
>   original blessedness. 
>  The remission of sins, therefore, is
>   granted alike to all through baptism: but the grace of the Spirit is
>   proportional to the faith and previous purification. Now, indeed, we
>   receive the firstfruits of the Holy Spirit through baptism, and the
>   second birth is for us the beginning and seal and security and
>   illumination of another life